# How to Scale an SVG Node Via SVG C# Library

Tags: c#, xpath, svg, png, transformation

I am attempting to scale an SVG before saving it out to a PNG so that when the application calls it at different "zoom" levels, the image is not pixelated. I am trying to use this library https://github.com/vvvv/SVG, but as there is no documentation, I tried supplementing it with HTMLAgilityPack which uses normal xpath selection, and then adding transform styles to the node itself. It seems though that the SVG C# library doesn't take the scale transform into consideration when dealing with reading, drawing, and saving the file, so the canvas doesn't scale correctly.

I have no idea how to really use SVG C#, apart from very basic things like opening and saving files. I can't make heads or tails of how to select nodes or apply transformations. Can someone assist?

```
public void svgToPng(string svgFileContents,string fileName)
{
        var svgDocument = SvgDocument.Open(svgFileContents);
        string workingPath = svgFileContents.Replace(".svg", "_working.svg");
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(workingPath))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(workingPath);
        }
        var workingSvgDocument = SvgDocument.Open(svgFileContents).GetXML();
        HtmlDocument theDocument = new HtmlDocument();
        theDocument.LoadHtml(workingSvgDocument);
        HtmlNodeCollection theNodes = theDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//svg");
        foreach (var node in theNodes)
        {
            
            decimal decimalWidth = Convert.ToDecimal(sizeOfSprites - (sizeOfSprites*.1));
            int oldWidth = Int32.Parse(node.GetAttributeValue("width",null).Replace("px",""));
            int oldHeight = Int32.Parse(node.GetAttributeValue("height",null).Replace("px",""));
            decimal percentChange = decimalWidth / oldWidth;
            int newWidth = Convert.ToInt32(decimalWidth);
            int newHeight = Convert.ToInt32(oldHeight * percentChange);
            node.SetAttributeValue("width", newWidth.ToString() + "px");
            node.SetAttributeValue("height", newHeight.ToString() + "px");
            node.SetAttributeValue("viewbox", "0 0 " + newWidth.ToString() + " " + newHeight.ToString());
            node.SetAttributeValue("enable-background", "new 0 0 " + newWidth.ToString() + " " + newHeight.ToString());
            node.SetAttributeValue("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinyMin meet");
            //node.SelectSingleNode("g").SetAttributeValue("style", "fill:purple;transform:scale("+Convert.ToDouble(percentChange)+")");
            HtmlNode svgRoot = node.ParentNode;
            HtmlNode newSvgParent = theDocument.CreateElement("svg");
            newSvgParent.SetAttributeValue("baseprofile", "full");
            newSvgParent.SetAttributeValue("width", "100%");
            newSvgParent.SetAttributeValue("height", "100%");
            newSvgParent.SetAttributeValue("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");
            newSvgParent.SetAttributeValue("xmlns:xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");
            newSvgParent.SetAttributeValue("xmlns:ev", "http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events");
            newSvgParent.AppendChild(node);
            svgRoot.ReplaceChild(newSvgParent, node);
            node.Attributes.Remove("xmlns");
            node.Attributes.Remove("xmlns:xlink");
            break;
        }
        theDocument.Save(workingPath);
        var output = SvgDocument.Open(workingPath);
        //output = SvgDocument.Open.Nodes.Select(Func < noclue, nodocumentation > stuck).Transform.Scale.?
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(svgFileContents.Replace(".svg",".png")))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(svgFileContents.Replace(".svg",".png"));
        }
        var bitmap = output.Draw();
        bitmap.Save(svgFileContents.Replace(".svg",".png"), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

Comment: It's more likely that setting transforms as attributes rather than styles will work. FWIW xMinyMin is wrong it's xMinYMin

Comment: Thank you for identifying the problem with the preserveAspectRatio string. I set the transformation via attribute directly and this did not have a different effect than setting it in the style attribute. I am using this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16453446/right-aligned-coordinates-in-svg for getting the contents aligned to the left of the viewport, because I am trying to standardize output of svgs of varying widths. It seems that the SVG.net library retains the path's original size as the canvas size if width/height of the outer <svg> are set to 100%. Is there a fix?

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is:

```
var svgDocument = SvgDocument.Open(f);
using (var bitmap = svgDocument.Draw(500,0))
{                      
   bitmap.Save(output500pixWide);
}
```

Draw takes a width and height. If one of width or height is 0 the output scales using the aspect ratio.